# Caching in WCF without ASP.NET Compatibility mode

Tags: c#, wcf, caching

I'm trying to come up with a caching strategy for a WCF service operation on a host that does not have ASP.NET Compatibility enabled (and can't for business reasons).  I like the syntax of the asp.net stuff

```
 [AspNetCacheProfile("CacheProfile1")]
 public GetPrincipalResp GetPrincipal(GetPrincipalReq req)
 {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
```

But obviously, it doesn't work.

For now, something simple would work fine but I can't seem to find anything that uses the same syntax.

Comment: Can't you use `Sessions` in WCF operations?

Comment: .NET 4.0+ has [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) in the System.Runtime.Caching namespace.  Take a look at that.